# VS Code - pylinter cannot find module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I started using VS Code for Python development on a Mac and cannot make `pylint` find a module.

This is my project folder structure:

```
project_root/
   .env
   .vscode/
       settings.json
   lib/
       # lib containing necessary modules
   sample/
       client/
           EDAMTest.py
   # many more files
```

I use a virtualenv in which I have installed `pylint`. The virtual env is activated in the terminal. I started `code` from within `project_root` folder via `code .` in my terminal.

VS Code says it is using the correct interpreter. I can see on the bottom left that it says `Python 3.6.1 (virtualenv)`

If I want to test the `project_root/sample/client/EDAMTest.py` code within terminal I can do it via `export PYTHONPATH=../../lib; python EDAMTest.py` while being in folder `project_root/sample/client/`.

Now if I am in VS Code, open the file `EDAMTest.py`, `pylint` is telling me that it cannot import modules from `lib`.

Now my question:

How can I add `lib` to `PYTHONPATH` in VS Code?

I found several possible ways to do so:

1. Create a `.env` file (see [1] below).
2. Specify `PYTHONPATH` in `.vscode/launch.json` file (see [2])

None of the possible solutions I found seem to work.

What am I missing?

---

[1] [Environment variable definitions file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file)

This tells me how to define global (env) vars. So I specified this:

`PYTHONPATH="~/.virtualenvs/evernote/bin/python;lib"`

But it won't work. Still `lib`s path is not found by `pylint`

---

[2] So I did create a `launch.json` file like so:

```
{
    "name": "Python",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
    "program": "${file}",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "debugOptions": [
        "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
        "WaitOnNormalExit",
        "RedirectOutput"
    ],
    "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "~/.virtualenvs/evernote/bin/python:lib"
    }
}
```

### ---

EDIT

Here is a link that tries to address this problem:

[Troubleshooting linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_troubleshooting-linting)

That link tries to address several possible problems, one is this:

> ... unable to import

The suggested solution is:

> Ensure that the `pythonPath` setting points to a valid Python installation where Pylint is installed.

=> Yes, I did.

> Alternately, set the `python.linting.pylintPath` to an appropriate version of Pylint for the Python interpreter being used.

=> I did, still no success:

My `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "~/.virtualenvs/evernote/bin/python",
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "~/.virtualenvs/evernote/bin/pylint"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that I had to use a colon instead of a semicolon in `.env` file like so: `PYTHONPATH="~/.virtualenvs/evernote/bin/python:lib"`. That seems to solve the problem.

Comment: What do you use for "python.pythonPath"  setting? If I don't set that up, VScode will use a different python installation (when you have multiple). But the import now works, thanks!