# Unable to find/ import .py file in the same directory Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have been all over the internet and spent hours trying to fix this. It may be something pretty straight forward so please cut me some slack. This is my first time using Visual Studio Code. I have already tried the solutions presented in the links below:

1. [VS Code - pylinter cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52080291/vs-code-pylinter-cannot-find-module)
2. [vscode import error for python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520127/vscode-import-error-for-python-module)
3. [Can't get VSCode/Python debugger to find my project modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290328/cant-get-vscode-python-debugger-to-find-my-project-modules)
4. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

[My folder structure looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5WG3.png)

I am trying to run the urls.py file which tries to import the views file using-

```
from . import views
```

But I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/abc/projects/telusko/calc/urls.py", line 7, in 
from . import views
ImportError: cannot import name 'views'

I have tried all possible combinations, and currently my launch.json file looks like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }],
    "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "c:/Users/abc/projects/telusko/"},
    "python.pythonPath": "c:/Users/abc/Envs/test/Scripts/python.exe" 
}
```

I am using a virtual env to run this project, the env is located at - "c:/Users/abc/projects/telusko/test/"

And my project directory is located at -

"c:/Users/abc/projects/telusko/"

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` should not point to the executable, but to the root of your project and then (separated by a colon) other places to look for.

Comment: Tried that, does not work. Updated code in question above to reflect latest version of the launch.json file.

Comment: this may be an alternative to VS https://spacevim.org/

Comment: Hi @Armagon can you please elaborate?

Comment: does this help to resolve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the folder where VS Code is open is the same folder as the file you have open. You have TELUSKO open and have access to all folders/files in that dir. But urls.py is in the `calc` dir.

It [looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5WG3.png) like your VS Code directory is TELUSKO which contains the folders and files:

- .idea/
- .vscode/
- calc/
- telusko/
- db.sqlite3
- manage.py

Thus, ANY files you open will only have access to these folders/files. Even if you open a file in a different directory.

To test this, type `import manage` and you will see it works even though there is no manage.py file in the calc/ dir.

You have 2 solutions:

1. Open a new VS Code window in the calc/ dir. Then you can run `import views` or `import apps` or `import test`... all of the files in calc/ are now available to you!
2. Do an absolute import. Your current dir is TELUSKO/, so do `from calc import views`.

Answer (score 0):

I create a project with the same folder structure as yours and the venv is called env under the folder test.

[image]
the urls.py and views.py are the same level modules, so the import sentence should be

```
from views import *
```

and the method os.getcwd() is to show your current working directory.

Comment: Hi Molly, Are you saying that I should move my env folder to the project folder? Because currently they are in different locations? Could you please elaborate on how you got the env (venv) folder/file.

Comment: Hi Molly, I tried following your instructions - moving my venv under the project root. But am still getting the same error.

Comment: Nope, in your question, you say the  the env is located  at c:/users/abc/projects/telusko/test, so i put my venv under the telusko/test to mostly copy and recreate your error. let env alone first, let me check, you want to import views.py in calc/urls.py, right? please comment all other code in calc/urls.py, and run import os print (os.getcwd()) and show me the output

Comment: In calc/urls.py I have the following code: --- 
from django.urls import path
import os
print(os.getcwd())
from views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home')
]
----
The output i get is this ___
(test) C:\Users\abc\projects\telusko>c:/Users/abc/Envs/test/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/abc/projects/telusko/calc/urls.py
C:\Users\abc\projects\telusko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/abc/projects/telusko/calc/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    path('', views.home, name='home')
NameError: name 'views' is not defined

Comment: try to run the code in my answer's screenshot, if still error, try to use from calc.views import *

Comment: from calc.views import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'calc'

Comment: ok, have you tried import sys sys.path.append('../') from views import *

Comment: Tried this but getting another error - NameError: name 'views' is not defined

Comment: For reference, I am exactly following this tutorial on my windows machine - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTmQOjsl0eg  .........................................................................stuck at around 28:00 mins into the video.

Comment: i've wathed the part you learned and there are some things i need to know: 1. the output about just run import os print(os.getcwd())  2.try this:when you open the project in vscode, type python -m venv .venv in terminal to create a new environment and select it as you current project's interpreter, then press ctrl+shift+` to refresh the terminal, try to run the import code again. I'll do some research regarding this error and update u later.

Comment: Thanks, will try this out and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a simple solution for this problem

you need to tell the VSCode : where your desired Files are !
first of all notice that every file that you want to import, must be in the same directory as your main .py File

click on File and then click : Open Folder

then go to the directory that encompasses all of .py Files that you want to import inside each other

then click open

VSCode will show a tree and you will see your .py files in the tree

now you can import them inside the other one

Answer (score -2):

My answer may have been poorly phrased so let me be more clear.

I'm suggesting VIM as a replacement for your entire process.  
You don't need VScode or any other IDE, You don't need Pylint, and you don't need to create any virtual environment.

Trying to simplify whatever problem it is your having in creating this "virtual environment" that's causing the error "Unable to find/ import .py file in the same directory Visual Studio Code", by replacing it ALL with VIM.

When I say "This will require additional work and research on your part" it's because Idk if VIM can be configured to do all the things Pylint can do because I don't know what Pylint can do.

You can check this out: https://realpython.com/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/

And if you're interested:
**Edit: Link replaced with direct GitHub repository**
https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases

**This is probably something you should be aware of and consider as well:**
*VIM was made for LINUX so future issues you may have could result in it being harder for you to find "Windows" solutions.*

Comment: @kiedi-If you tried that previous install plz discard and use GitHub repository instead

Comment: Thanks @armagon, I shall try this out

Comment: I don't think that moving to the VI editor is a good advise.  It is about the worst editor on the planet IMHO.   I am not interested in moving from an IDE like VS Code to an esoteric hard to use editor like vim or vi.  I would rather give up coding.